# is it possible to write a dynamic ' abstract / shared ' trait in rust

Tags: rust

edit:

- [link to playground with possible solution](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=9e7e8ab4ab5051252da7ba20545362f6) based on [Locke's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64252682/5011027)
- [link to playground with abstract trait example without generics](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=5bc8eca4d4c23851022f987c8f12411d)

#### original question

In `MyTrait` I try to share the complicated functionality `doSth`

MyTrait is implemented for Foo.

Foo has an inner struct `bar` which shall be of type `T`.
The implementation shall prevent rewriting some other functionality for each `T`.

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum Status{
    Open,
    Closed,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Foo<T>{
    name: String,
    status: Status,
    bar: T
    
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum SomeError {
    Fails,
}

pub trait MyTrait<T> {
    type Output;
    
    fn setStatus(&self, status: Status) -> Status;
    fn getStatus(&self) -> Status;

    fn doSth(&self) -> Result<Self::Output, SomeError>
    {
        if super::variant_eq(&self.getStatus(), &Status::Closed) {
            self.setStatus(Status::Open);
            return Ok(T);
        };
        return Err(SomeError::Fails);
    }

}

impl<T> MyTrait<T> for Foo<T> {
    type Output = Foo<T>;

    fn setStatus(&self, status: Status) -> Status{
        self.status = status;
    }

    fn getStatus(&self) -> Status{
        self.status;
    }
    
}
```

`doSth` doesn't compile (others probably not either, it didn't go that far yet)

- With the expected return to `Result<Self::Output, SomeError>` and the actual return to `return Ok(T)` the compiler says `T is not a value`
- With the expected return to `Result<Self::Output, SomeError>` and the actual return to `return Ok(Self::Output)` the compiler says
  `` associated item not found in `Self` ``
- With the expected return to `Result<T, SomeError>` and the actual return to `return Ok(())` the compiler says `expected type parameter T, found ()`

I do find examples for generics, examples for shared functions, but nothing for that approach, thus I am not certain if the approach is reasonable.

If it is justified to work in this direction, what would be the way forward?

Comment: `T` is not a value but a type parameter, and `Self::Output` is not a value either. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to contain a [mre]. If possible, try to recreate the error you're getting on the [Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/). The code you have posted does demonstrate the error, so thanks for that, but it also has other errors that don't seem related, like ``error[E0433]: failed to resolve: there are too many leading `super` keywords``. Please try to eliminate irrelevant errors. Finally, please explain what you would like the code to do if it had worked, because it's not clear what you were expecting `return Ok(T)` to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, `Status` should derive `PartialEq` so you can check equality. Implementing your own `variant_eq` function for an `enum` is almost always the incorrect approach.

I would also recommend deriving `Copy` for ease of use.

```rust
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq, Copy, Clone)]
pub enum Status {
    Open,
    Closed,
}
```

With all that, here some quick comments on how to make your code function correctly

```rust
pub trait MyTrait<T> {
    type Output;
    
    // This set should probably take a mutable reference
    fn set_status(&mut self, status: Status);
    fn get_status(&self) -> Status;

    // You need some way to get output
    fn get_output(&mut self) -> Self::Output;

    // Now it has everything it needs to work correctly.
    fn doSth(&mut self) -> Result<Self::Output, SomeError> {
        // Thanks to PartialEq we can use == as normal
        if self.getStatus() == Status::Closed {
            self.set_status(Status::Open);

            // Call function that will be implemented later to provide output
            return Ok(self.get_output())
        }

        // Return is assumed for last line in function
        Err(SomeError::Fails)
    }
}
```

Even if you can't derive `PartialEq`, you can at least use a match.

```rust
match self.getStatus() {
    Status::Closed => {
        self.set_status(Status::Open);
        Ok(self.get_output())
    }
    _ => Err(SomeError::Fails),
}
```

With all that, you can then implement foo similarly to your origional.

```rust
impl<T> MyTrait<T> for Foo<T> {
    type Output = Foo<T>;

    // Required mutable reference to work
    fn set_status(&mut self, status: Status) {
        self.status = status;
    }

    fn get_status(&self) -> Status {
        // ; would have prevented value from being returned
        // Status also needs to implement Copy for this to work
        self.status
    }
    
    fn get_output(&mut self) -> Self::Output {
        // Since you have it return an owned value, you need to either clone
        // self, or make get_output consume self
        self.clone()
    }
}
```

Comment: I had to adapt your suggestion a bit, so that clone worked.  [it is here in Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=9e7e8ab4ab5051252da7ba20545362f6)

Comment: @til You have `Clone` bounds in three places, but [only one is necessary](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=4e3542e123e16cd6a396aa0134771a3b).